# Printing struct array data causing reboot on Atmega 2560

Tags: c++, struct, arduino

I have a custom PCB accommodating ATmega2560 MCU. I'm using Atmel Studio 7 for fuses and flashing the HEX. I'm using Visual Studio with Visual Micro plug-in using a mix of C/C++ and Arduino coding.

I have a struct array definition.

**Definition:**

```
#define MAX_RECORDS 20 //Max number of records in the struct

typedef struct Record {
    uint8_t id;//unique number to define data sequence
    uint8_t sec;
    uint8_t obj;
    uint16_t xs;
    uint16_t ys;
    uint16_t xe;
    uint16_t ye;
    uint8_t clr;
    uint8_t tsz;
    uint8_t tid;
} tRecord;

struct Record recordsOut[MAX_RECORDS];
```

**This is how I print the data to the Serial output:**

```
void ListDesignData() {
    Serial.println("========================================");
    Serial.println("Design data in non-volatile memory:");
    //int size = sizeof recordsOut / sizeof recordsOut[0];
    //Serial.print("Design Size:");
    //Serial.println(size);
    Serial.println("========================================");
    uint8_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_RECORDS; i++)
    {
        if (recordsOut[i].id != 255) {
            delay(10);
            Serial.print("id:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].id);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("sec:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].sec);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("obj:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].obj);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("xs:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].xs);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("xe:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].xe);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("ye:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].ye);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("clr:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].clr);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("tsz:"); Serial.print(recordsOut[i].tsz);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print("tid:"); Serial.println(recordsOut[i].tid);
        }
    }
    Serial.print(getPSTR("Old way to force String to Flash"));
    Serial.println(F("Free RAM 3 = ")); //F function does the same and is now a built in library, in IDE > 1.0.0
    Serial.println(freeMemory(), DEC); // print how much RAM is available.

    Serial.println("========================================");
}
```

After all the print code runs, it causes MCU to reboot.
In order to see the memory consumption, I am using a library. But, it doesn't reveal any lack of memory. (or am I probing it at a wrong moment/place?)

**Here is the output I get on a serial monitor:**

```
========================================
Design data in non-volatile memory:
========================================
id:1,sec:1,obj:1,xs:1,xe:157,ye:60,clr:0,tsz:0,tid:0
id:2,sec:1,obj:2,xs:1,xe:158,ye:60,clr:2,tsz:0,tid:0
id:3,sec:1,obj:3,xs:5,xe:0,ye:0,clr:2,tsz:2,tid:1
id:4,sec:2,obj:1,xs:1,xe:158,ye:60,clr:0,tsz:0,tid:0
id:5,sec:2,obj:2,xs:1,xe:158,ye:60,clr:2,tsz:0,tid:0
id:6,sec:2,obj:3,xs:5,xe:0,ye:0,clr:2,tsz:2,tid:1
Old way to force String to FlashFree RAM 3 = 
4882
========================================
```

EDIT: Here is also how that function is called:

```
void loop() {
    serialEvent(); //Listens input from serial 
    ProcessCommands(); //Process received serial commands and call functions accordingly. In our case, the function is ListDesignData().
}
```

So, how to find the bottle-neck and fix this issue?
Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have Atmel Studio 7.0, you have the Simulator for ATmega2560. You should try debugging you code line by line and see what is happening. If it's works ok in simulator, then you can isolate the problem to PCB setup / proper toolchain settings  or the initialization routine.

Comment: The problem is most likely not in `ListDesignData()`, since it finishes correctly before rebooting. Where is this function called?

Comment: @G. Sliepen, I have edited my post in order to give some idea how the function is called. I use Serial input coming from PC's USB. But, I have also "Serial to TCP" module connected to another serial port of the mcu. If I use that port to print same thing, it does work OK, no rebooting occurs.
I suspect from the baud-rate. TCP part is using 115200 and USB part is using 38400. Since I don't have access to my code but tomorrow, I can't test it yet.

Comment: fyi, I have changed the baudrate to 115200 from 38400 but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure it reboots, or is it just that the function `loop()` is called in a loop, as the name implies?

Comment: There is only one `loop()`. It is more like an error occurs somewhere and causes an avalanche effect and a crash and a reboot eventually. But, rarely, it just causes a complete stop and doing nothing. Then I have to reboot it manually to recover.